# svg css rounded corner not working

Tags: css, html, svg, rounded-corners

I have an SVG file that I am applying CSS to. Most rules seem to work, but when I apply rules about the rounding of corners (rx:5; ry:5) it has no effect. 'Inline' style rules work, but I'm having no luck with embedded and external style sheets:

```
<svg ...>
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css" >
    <![CDATA[
     rect{ rx:5; ry:5;  }
    ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>

 <rect
    height="170" width="70" id="rect7"
    x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

rx and ry are regular attributes rather than presentation attributes. Only presentation attributes can be styled by CSS. The various regular/presentation attributes are listed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html)

See also [Presentation Attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermPresentationAttribute) and [Property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermProperty) from the SVG 1.1 specification.

The upcoming SVG 2 specification proposes that most presentation attributes become CSS properties. So far Chrome and Firefox have implemented this part of the draft specification. I imagine other UAs will implement this in due course.

Comment: that explains it, thanks.  Is there any way to adjust the rounding of svg like you can in css with `border-radius: 5px;`

Comment: This is the obvious answer: <rect height="170" width="70" rx="5" ry="5" id="rect7" />

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer with the question, is there any way a style sheet or alternative can be applied to achieve the same effect, as CSS3 now allows through`border-radius: 5px;`?  I'm not dynamically creating the SVGs and they are being used on different websites with different general styles.  Is the only way to 'inline' it or write javascript to change it on the fly?  Thanks again for the help

Comment: Thanks for the update Robert, I've just watched this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL2-ZAyvXOM and it all looks very exciting

Answer (score 16):

Scripting can't be simpler, why not to use it:

```
 yourRect.setAttributeNS(null, "rx", "5");
 yourRect.setAttributeNS(null, "ry", "5");
```

Comment: Why with html5 elements we must use `setAttributeNS ` instead of `setAttribute`

Comment: but what if i want to update only top corner radius like `border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;`  this cant be ahieved with `rx` or `ry`. Have you got any idea how to achieve it ?